# How to execute SQL scripts with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a database in Spark, and for this purpose, I have written a few SQL scripts which create the SQL tables.
My question is, how to integrate the SQL tables (the database) into Spark for later processing?
Could that be done using a Scala script or through the Spark console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Scala :

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
 val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("execute-query-files") 
    .master("local[*]") //since the jar will be executed locally
    .getOrCreate()
                         
val sqlQuery = Source.fromFile("path/to/data.sql").mkString //read file
spark.sql(sqlQuery) //execute query
```

Where spark is your spark session, already created.

Comment: OK, and for sparkSession what is the config to specify using the `Builder().config()`?
Also how to read the  SQL script using JAVA ?
PS : `data.sql` is the script defining tables (e.g CREATE TABLE ...) ?

Comment: where do you excute your code , in local or in the cloud ?

Comment: Local, Also to run the JAVA / Scala program, you should package it and then use `spark-submit` on the .jar is that correct ?

Comment: Ahh I see so you can use scala it is better when working with spark , for the spark session i will add it in the response you can use the configuratio by default .